# Android app to correctly indicate battery wear

Tags: android, battery, power-management

Please recommend an Android app that correctly indicates battery wear.

What is battery wear?  After a Lithium-Ion (Li-Ion) battery has been repeatedly discharged and recharged, it will no longer hold it's full capacity.

For example, a battery, when new, might hold 3500mAh of [energy](https://www.ubergizmo.com/what-is/mah-milliamp-hours/).  After it has been discharged and recharged 100 times, it might only hold 3200mAh of energy.  I'm looking for an app that can correctly determine that second value.

A gratis, open-source, ad-free app is preferred, but none of those preferences are requirements.

Answer (score 1):

#### [AccuBattery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digibites.accubattery&rdid=com.digibites.accubattery)

I've recently started using AccuBattery. It gives an indication of battery wear by estimating the current capacity and comparing it to the design capacity (user input). This is basically your main requirement. Below is a screenshot from my phone:

[image]

It also has other useful monitoring and optimization features for improving battery heath and lifetime.

Concerning your other preferences, the app is not open source, but it cites the research papers used for some of its functions. It's also not gratis or ad-free, but in my opinion their business model is reasonable. The free version is ad supported with a one-time in-app purchase to remove ads and unlock design Pro features, such as dark mode.